# eclipse search for a type in current java file

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I search for a variable who has a certain type? For example, I have a huge class with thousands of lines code, pile of fields and a ton of comments and I need to find if there's a field of type, say String in that class. Is there any cleverer way than use Find to blindly match all occurrence of "String", which appears a lot in comments and other function calls. Using Outline is not an option because there are too many fields for human eye to pick and it's not sorted by type. I also tried Java search with search string "String", search for type and limited to declarations but I either get 0 matches even though on a test file which has a string declaration or it always step out of the current source code file. Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find every field with a certain type:

- Go to Search > Java
- Enter the type you want to search in the text box (`java.lang.String`
  or just `String`)
- Select "Type" in the "Search For" section
- Click the link next to "Match locations" in the "Limit To" section
  [image]
- In the dialog that pops up, select "Field types" and hit "OK"
  [image]
- Select the source file in the Package Explorer or in the Editor, hit "Selected Resources" in the "Scope" section
- Hit the "Search" button
- Happy hunting

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Java Search](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-search.htm&resultof=%22search%22%20%22java%22).  It is a very handy tool for searching a Java project.

---

*PS. A single class/file with thousands of lines is probably not well designed and should be  refactored into multiple classes each with a concise responsibility.*